# Weblogic, error deploying application

Tags: java, ejb, weblogic

I have an application in that works in Weblogic 10.3.4 and I want to migrate it to 12.1.3, but when the Weblogic server is deploying the application I get this error:

> weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> java.lang.Exception: Exception received from deployment driver.   at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.DeploymentProgressListener.watch(DeploymentProgressListener.java:188)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.deploy(WlsJ2EEDeploymentHelper.java:509)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishWeblogicModules(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:1504)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishToServer(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:921)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publishOnce(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:709)
>     at
>   oracle.eclipse.tools.weblogic.server.internal.WeblogicServerBehaviour.publish(WeblogicServerBehaviour.java:556)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.model.ServerBehaviourDelegate.publish(ServerBehaviourDelegate.java:774)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server.publishImpl(Server.java:3154)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.wst.server.core.internal.Server$PublishJob.run(Server.java:345)
>     at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53) Caused
>   by: weblogic.application.ModuleException:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:123)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.activate(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:114)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:195)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$2.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:190)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.activate(ModuleStateDriver.java:61)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.flow.DeploymentCallbackFlow.activate(DeploymentCallbackFlow.java:145)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:61)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:80)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:587)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:339)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:846)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1275)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:442)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:176)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
>     at
>   weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
>     at
>   weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:548)
>     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)  at
>   weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException:   at
>   javax.naming.Reference.equals(Reference.java:332)     at
>   weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.bindHere(BasicNamingNode.java:365)
>     at
>   weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.bind(BasicNamingNode.java:330)
>     at
>   weblogic.jndi.internal.BasicNamingNode.bind(BasicNamingNode.java:337)
>     at
>   weblogic.jndi.internal.WLEventContextImpl.bind(WLEventContextImpl.java:280)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.naming.GeneralPortableJNDIBinder.bindWithPortableJNDIName(GeneralPortableJNDIBinder.java:81)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.naming.GeneralPortableJNDIBinder.bind(GeneralPortableJNDIBinder.java:53)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindResourceEnvReference(EnvironmentBuilder.java:1023)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindResourceEnvReferences(EnvironmentBuilder.java:1015)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindResourceEnvReferences(EnvironmentBuilder.java:1394)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.naming.EnvironmentBuilder.bindEnvEntriesFromDDs(EnvironmentBuilder.java:1948)
>     at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.activateEnvironment(EJBDeployer.java:1080)
>     at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBDeployer.activate(EJBDeployer.java:850)
>     at
>   weblogic.ejb.container.deployer.EJBModule.activate(EJBModule.java:488)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$ActivateStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:317)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$ActivateStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:313)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
>     at
>   weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.activate(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:121)

Comment: There is good Oracle documentation on moving from 10.3 to 12.1. See if this info helps: http://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/wls/WLUPG/upgrade_ws.htm It's highly dependent on what shared libraries you use. The error itself probably isn't enough information for someone to be able to help

Comment: can you provide full stacktrace?

Comment: it mentions env references (bindResourceEnvReference) can you tell us if your app using java:comp/env kind of look up, if yes, how are you resolving it?